# Como fazer commit utilizando linha de comando no SVN

Tags: linux, svn, linha-de-comando, commit

A pasta foi criada vazia no SVN.

Preciso colocar o conteúdo nela, mas não quero fazer um por um todos as adições de arquivos e pastas.

Estou no linux e gostaria de fazer por linha de comando, mas ainda não consegui, usei os comandos:

```
svn commit PASTA -m 'Comentario
```

Mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro tem que adicionar os arquivos com o comando:

```
svn add *
```